# Android - Trying to get a PlaceBufferResponse from a Task using mGeoDataClient.getPlaceById(id), but failed

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I was trying to get a place's information using Google's GeoDataClient in Android using Android studio. 
Specifically, I have set up a OnPoiClicklistener, so when a point of interest is clicked, a marker shows and a InfoWindow appears to show the details. To get the details, I used the GeoDataClient's getPlaceById(id) method. As shown below:

```
Task<PlaceBufferResponse> placeBufferResponseTask = mGeoDataClient.getPlaceById(mPlaceId);
placeBufferResponseTask.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<PlaceBufferResponse>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<PlaceBufferResponse> task) {
        try {
            PlaceBufferResponse bufferResponse = task.getResult();
            final Place resultPlace = bufferResponse.get(0);

            placeName.setText(resultPlace.getName());
            placeType.setText(resultPlace.getPlaceTypes().get(0));
            placeAddress.setText(resultPlace.getAddress());


            bufferResponse.release();
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Place query did not complete.", e);
            }
        }
```

However, I always get an error, with the logcat as shown below:

12-16 10:31:22.735 7218-7218/com.justinlee.whichpay E/MapsActivity: Place query did not complete.
                                                                    com.google.android.gms.tasks.RuntimeExecutionException: com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 13: ERROR
                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzn.getResult(Unknown Source)
                                                                        **at com.justinlee.whichpay.MapsActivity$5.onComplete(MapsActivity.java:363)**
                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzf.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                                                                     Caused by: com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 13: ERROR
                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzb.zzy(Unknown Source)
                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzbk.zzz(Unknown Source)
                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzbl.zzr(Unknown Source)
                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzs.zzc(Unknown Source)
                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzs.setResult(Unknown Source)
                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.location.places.zzm.zzar(Unknown Source)
                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.location.places.internal.zzx.onTransact(Unknown Source)
                                                                        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:565)

The problems seems to be occuring on the bolded line, which has reference to

```
PlaceBufferResponse bufferResponse = task.getResult();
```

from the code. Can anyone help? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're modifying the UI from the background thread with these statement:

```
placeName.setText(resultPlace.getName());
placeType.setText(resultPlace.getPlaceTypes().get(0));
placeAddress.setText(resultPlace.getAddress());
```

If you want to do so, you need to use a handler to queue the modifying action to UI thread, full code will look like this:

```
placeBufferResponseTask.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<PlaceBufferResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<PlaceBufferResponse> task) {
            try {
                PlaceBufferResponse bufferResponse = task.getResult();
                final Place resultPlace = bufferResponse.get(0);

                Handler mainHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

                Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        placeName.setText(resultPlace.getName());
                        placeType.setText(resultPlace.getPlaceTypes().get(0));
                        placeAddress.setText(resultPlace.getAddress());
                    }
                };
                mainHandler.post(myRunnable);

                bufferResponse.release();
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Place query did not complete.", e);
            }

    }
```

Or you can use method `runOnUiThread` of [activity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I just got it working using your solution!